# What is the convention about class method return this pointer

Tags: c++

Or in a class method, call other class' method/free function and pass this pointer as the parameter. Is there any good practice for this? Or it is a bad practice and I should not doing so?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It usually makes **no sense** to return the `this` pointer from class meber functions. 
(since the caller must be already holding a reference to the instance,, to call the method/operator in question, and you cannot change it returning di9fferent values anyway).

It **makes sense** to return `*this` from various types of member functions (specific operators in particular, e.g. `operator=()`), to enable chaining of operations on results.

**NOTE**:
Some of the overloadable operator signatures (as the mentioned assignment operator) **require** to implement such behavior to work correctly with the semantics defined by C++!